# My variable returns an invalid syntax and i don't know why

Tags: python

I am new to python, just picked it up again after a long time. My code is here basically a die rolling simulator and I can't seem to figure out the "invalid syntax" I get after the second line.
my code ----> https://pastebin.com/XPNq0tup
Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
from random import randint
var = raw_imput("How many dices do you want, 1 or 2?"
rollagain = 'yes'
```

the rollagain variable is where I encounter the error.

Comment: There is unclosed parenthesis in the previous line in `raw_input`.

Comment: Standard procedure for syntax errors you don't get: go back a line, check your parentheses.

Comment: Also it should be `raw_input` instead of `raw_imput`

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there ! 
Just one ending bracket and change in name of function "raw_input" instead of "raw_imput" and its all done.

```
from random import randint
var = raw_input("How many dices do you want, 1 or 2?")
rollagain = 'yes'
```

Comment: It should be `raw_input`